# Rely my android app to json file in the web

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, feed

Here is the thing, i want to retrieve some news into my android application which i could find in a json file.
I was thinking about creating some blog(wordpress maybe) and by adding articles, it automatically add it into the json file.
In this way, after relying my app to the json file, all i need to do is adding articles in the blog.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: well, i don't know how to proceed, i mean what's the best to create articles somewhere which will automatically generate json file

Comment: WordPress will generate RSS files which you can easily consume from Android.

Comment: Do not post to StackOverflow without research first. You should simple Google "how to retrieve JSON". Start there and do not come back until you have some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After app started load JSON from server.
2. Parse it to app content.
3. Add posibility for manual refresh with SwipeRefreshLayout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html
4. If you need your app update JSON automatically, after new post added to blog your should use Google Cloud Messaging. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/?hl=ru